How can I retrieve the JWT from Google authentication using Auth.js in Next.js?
//auth.config.ts
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth";

export const authConfig = {
  pages: {
    signIn: `/`,
  },

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      return { ...session, token };
    },
    authorized({ auth, request: { nextUrl } }) {
      const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user;
      const isOnDashboard = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/dashboard/overview");
      if (isOnDashboard) {
        if (isLoggedIn) return true;
        console.log(nextUrl);

        return false; // Redirect unauthenticated users to login page
      } else if (isLoggedIn) {
        return Response.redirect(new URL("/dashboard/overview", nextUrl));
      }
      return true;
    },
  },
  session: { strategy: "jwt" },
  providers: [],
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;


// middleware.ts
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { authConfig } from "./auth.config";

export default NextAuth(authConfig).auth;

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/dashboard/:path*", "/"],
};


// auth.ts
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

import { authConfig } from "./auth.config";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  ...authConfig,
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.AUTH_GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AUTH_GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
});


// app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts
import { handlers } from "@/auth";
export const { GET, POST } = handlers;


when I try to get session inside component, I get an object which contains token but it's not in jwt format, it's an object which contains the logged in user details
import { auth } from "@/auth";

export default async function Overview() {
  const session = await auth();

  console.log(session); 


  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Overview</h1>
      <GoogleLogOutButton />
    </div>
  );
}

Object in log
{
    "user": {
        "name": "Abc xyz",
        "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
        "image": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocKIvitYpcxdgnttIjoJt70mhvd5yXgxvxudeg"
    },
    "expires": "2024-12-27T17:28:00.662Z",
    "token": {
        "name": "Abc xyz",
        "email": "xyz@gmail.com",
        "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/ACg8ocKIvitYpcxdgnttIjoJt70mhvd5yXgxvwudcg",
        "sub": "ba322e37-ecb6-43dd-afd1-a1360abcde",
        "iat": 1732724444,
        "exp": 1735355555,
        "jti": "7b12fd9b-9484-4eb9-8df7-d5b25b3abcde"
    }
}

I want to get encoded jwt with alg RS256, previously in my react project I was using @react-oauth/google": "0.12.1, and it works. Now I am migrating my project to nextjs and using NextAuth(Auth.js) to authenticate using google. Have tried a couple of solutions but none of them seem to work.
